# Same product but different price based on GeoIP in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, geoip

I want GeoIP based pricing. Suppose I have a product A. The price of product A in India will be 10, but 20 in the UK. I do not want to add the same product again.

I want the same product but only price and tax changes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento already have this functionality. First of all you need to change the "Catalog Price Scope" from *Global* to *Website*. then you need to create 2 different websites or all the website you want to change the price.
I did the same you are asking in this site... http://www.worldflowersdelivery.com/

Let me know if this can help you.

Best,
GrinGo.

---

[edited] - How to request.

I'm going to skip a several steps to how to create a new website and all the configuration under the server you need to do and if you don't have access to the server the other way to add the information we need to setup to get a new website up and running.

So, we already setup all the server configuration to have a new website.

**Step 1:**

Go to *System > Configuration > Catalog > Price - Catalog Price Scope* change to **website** (be sure to under "Current Configuration Scope")

[image]

**Step 2:**

Check if you setup the same root category under the new Store created related to the new website.

[image]
[image]

**Step 3:**

Let configure the product after we complete al the store stuff.
First of all a new tab you are going to see called *websites* you need to check the new website we before created. (see the img.)
[image]
[image]

**Step 4:**
Let change the price for each of the website we want, to do that change the *Choose Store View* and set up the store view we want to change first. For the Default Store View let change the price to $200 then *save and continue editing* and change the sore scope to the other store view and change the price, changed to $250.

[image]
[image]

Let me know if the steps helps you, if you need anything else just let me know.

Best,
GrinGo.

Comment: can u give me link to tutorial or doc from step by step flow

Comment: Sure, let me creat one and I can share with you.

Comment: i had done step 1,2 but could not see page like step 3 http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/AMIfv96SPOj1H7wskB5WjIPqUqv9HAJIFiA5LNoxofshzv3YOZpNv3aGqWaajmONaMaCXRtYD7jvOyntalmWCxzo3B479fa5dWLtD1uToq3ZE5DIm71wHaZKupEtS6yUlFYQhDUlIaR6fHdba9bNFfFcL5A3O3OWEJTS782g2dYzmC4MZN1hvvE/Untitled.png

Comment: @saurav, here is the doc to create a website and all you need to configure. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup

Best,